# How to join list of figures with list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

This is my first post on this forum and I am turning on you for help with advanced problem. I am writing my thesis and I am using `listings` package for including code snippets. However, I don't use float environment with every snippet, because some of them needs more than 1 page. So I can't include them in figure environment. But I want code snippets to act as figures, so I set them to share counter and name with figures:

```
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Slika}
\let\c@lstlisting\c@figure
\let\thelstlisting\thefigure
\let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure
```

Now I have trouble adding them to list of figures just as they were figures. Numbering, captioning, referencing and everything works just as I want, but I can't add listings to list of figures. I tryed to google the answer, but it seems that no one before had this specific problem. I don't have enough knowledge with `LaTeX` to write any scripts or anything like that, so I ask you guys for help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  sorry i can't offer any technical expertise on this, only commiseration.

Comment: A list of figures or tables is actually a list of captions.  See \captionof from the caption or captionof packages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Yes, but `listings` uses a `caption` option in a key value interface. I don't think it's very easy to `listings`'s  caption mechanism to work with `\captionof`

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27738)

Answer (score 3):

**Update** See a shorter version without using a patch at the end the answer.

Some note before: A listing is a listing and not a figure, so merging listings and figures in the `LoF` is perhaps not the best way to apply those different concepts -- that's why there is a `\lstlistoflistings` command ;-)

`listings` uses `\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlistings}{...}` and this is hard-coded in `\lst@MakeCaption`. Either copy the code from `listings.sty` and change the settings or use a patch, that changes the relevant portions. In a normal setup, the 2nd `\addcontentsline{lol}{lstlistings}{...}` command is active.

Now, in order to prevent strange differences between a normal `lof` - line and a `lol` line, I suggest to use `\let\l@lstlisting\l@figure` as well!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{listings}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%

\xpatchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{%
  \lst@ifnolol\else
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@intname\@empty \else \def\lst@temp{ }%
  \ifx\lst@intname\lst@temp \else
  \addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}\lst@name
  \fi\fi
  \fi
  \else
  \addcontentsline{lol}{lstlisting}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
  \fi
  \fi
}{%
  \lst@ifnolol\else
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@caption\@empty
  \ifx\lst@intname\@empty \else \def\lst@temp{ }%
  \ifx\lst@intname\lst@temp \else
  \addcontentsline{lof}{lstlisting}\lst@name
  \fi\fi
  \fi
  \else
  \addcontentsline{lof}{lstlisting}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
  \fi
  \fi
}{\typeout{Patch success!}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}


\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Slika}
\let\l@lstlisting\l@figure
\let\c@lstlisting\c@figure
\let\thelstlisting\thefigure
\let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Hello World},label={foo}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}


\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**A shorter version without patching**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
% Grab the old \addcontentsline, which has been already being redefined by hyperref (eventually)
\let\latex@@addcontentsline\addcontentsline 

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
  \def\@@zzz{#1}\def\@@zxx{lol}
  \latex@@addcontentsline{%
    \ifx\@@zzz\@@zxx lof\else #1\fi
  }{#2}{#3}%
}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Slika}
\let\l@lstlisting\l@figure
\let\c@lstlisting\c@figure
\let\thelstlisting\thefigure
\let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Hello World},label={foo}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}


\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind answering the linked crosspost above as well?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done so ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You can shorten your redefinition using `\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{lol}=0 lof\else#1\fi}{#2}{#3}}`.

Comment: @Werner: That's shorter indeed, but won't compile if the user uses `latex` 'only' (ok, that's rather unlikely nowadays), I think.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: `\pdfstrcmp` is not just for pdflatex. Try it with latex only...

Comment: @Werner: Hm.... `\pdfstrcmp` is not defined neither by `hyperref` or by `latex.ltx` -- I wonder why this works...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: `\pdfstrcmp` is an expandable text comparison that forms part of pdfTeX 1.30.0+, which is run when you use LaTeX or pdfLaTeX. Look at the first line of your `.log` when you compile. Also see the [pdfTeX reference manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf).